# How to print Python variables after an error in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

When a script ends with an error during debugging, PyCharm got disconnected from `pydev`. So, the state of variable at the moment of the error remains unknown.

How can I find out the very latest values of variables right before the error happens?

Updated: This problem arises only when you try to debug a *unit test*. You have to check "Activation policy: On raise" for "All Breakpoints" in the list of breakpoints.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, pycharm does not use pydev. So it's hard to get a lock on what your issue is. Secondly, look into [try/catch structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html). Third, are you sure you want to do print debugging, as opposed to use a nice debugger itself?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I run PyCharm's debugger (and it says "Connected to pydev debugger (build 135.1057) pydev debugger: process 28034 is connecting").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be setting a breakpoint just before/at the wanted line so you can see the variables just before the exception is called.

It's also possible to set an "exception breakpoint". This stops the script when a specific exception is encountered. Open "Run" > "View Breakpoints", click on the "+" sign and add a "Python Exception Breakpoint". Now you have to choose a specific exception.

Comment: In this case, you delete the previous breakpoint and add an "exception breakpoint". Open Run > View Breakpoints, click on the "+" sign and add a "Python Exception Breakpoint". Now you have to choose a specific exception. That's it.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot. Maybe worth adding to the post itself.